# Wine has no or little smell to it

Tags: wine

I’m experimenting with mango wine and produced different batches using fresh local mangoes.

My latest batch has little or no smell to it. It basically smells like alcohol and the bouquet is otherwise weak with faint fruit aroma.

Recipe:

- 12L of fresh mango pulp (Mamuang Kaew cultivar)
- 6L of fresh water (reverse osmosis)
- 1800g of white sugar
- 6 tsp bentonite
- 12 tsp pectine enzyme
- 3 tsp campden.

> Initial ABV 1.080. Fermentation in controlled environment between 20° and 22° Celsius. Rack after 1 month, rack after another month, clear last cloud with 2 tsp of bentonite. Final ABV 0.990 Wine now 4 months old.

What can I do to increase bouquet in my next attempt?

Comment: Can you post your current recipe (all ingredients) please?

Comment: 12L of fresh mango pulp (Mamuang Kaew cultivar); 6L of fresh water (reverse osmosis); 180g of white sugar, 6 tbs bentonite, 12 tbs pectine enzyme, 3 tbs campden. Initial ABV 1.080. Rack after 1 month, rack after another month, clear last cloud with 2 tbs bentonite. Final ABV 0.990 Wine now 4 months old.

Comment: PS: fermentation in temp controlled cooler, 20 to 22 Celsius.

Comment: Let me understand this better? "3 tbs" campden. Is that TABLESPOONS or TABLETS? because if you put 3 tbs spoons in that small amount, you will strip just about everything out of the wine and it will get bleached. 3 tablets/pills is about right.

Comment: Sorry tbs is supposed to be tea spoon (wrongly abbreviated).

Comment: That's still too much campden.

Comment: No added yeast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your primary fruit lacks flavor to begin with, you will need to add something else to compensate.  Bouquet is very subjective, but still I will try to help:

1- Adding Tannin and using an Acid Blend will give it a little kick. Take a look at this recipe: https://practicalselfreliance.com/mango-wine/

2- There is also the choice of the yeast that can change the final result as well.

3- Not sure if adding hops would fit, but some people add hops to cider, then again, there are so many different hops that have their own flavour, but I would probabaly try one that that has Citrus flavour.

4- You may try to mix another fruit to add complexity.

That is all I can think of, for now.

Comment: Thanks. I’d disagree with your first statement as to the lack of flavor in fruit. I’m not sure as to what mangoes you’re used to but over here in south east Asia mangoes are flavorful and aromatic. I’m using one of the most aromatic mango cultivar which is so strong in smell it comes second to Durian.

Comment: This said I agree with some of the suggestions you made. Though I’m a little hesitant with tannin, I am trying adding some tamarind which is the highest tartaric acid containing fruit after grape, adding some of complexity and freshness with acidity.

Comment: True, unfortunately in northern countries fruits often travel to here a bit green and not as flavorful...   I tried to provide some ideas, difficult to say which will best suit you, best of luck in your trials.